# Should I allow user to have multiple TOTPs simulteneously?

Tags: architecture, multi-factor-authentication, two-factor-authentication, totp

In order to make my question more specific, I'd like to explain my task.

I'm trying to implement a component/service that's responsible for creating OTPs (namely, time-based ones).

**Note:** It doesn't really matter if a TOTP is sent via SMS or to user's email address.

For example, if user have forgotten their password and want to recover it, my system must verify this transaction and then allow them to change it.

Also, I'm going to create transaction types (probably, it will be an enum). This mechanism will help to distinguish one TOTP from another. It would be a security issue if I let user change their password using a TOTP which was created to change their email address for example.

The question is, should I allow each user to have multiple TOTPs for different transaction types?

For example, if user's requested a TOTP to change their password, should I allow them to request another one to change their email address (right after the first request, so now the user have two valid TOTPs pending to be used)?

Comment: I would perhaps question whether using TOTP is correct here, or whether you should simply generate a random token for a specific action and expire the token after a set period of time.

Comment: @philnash I thought about this and I've already implemeneted a similar mechanism. My service was creating random six-digit codes using standard Python library (random.choices, string.digits and then join() function). All codes were stored in Redis by a specific key that consisted of user ID and a string representation of a transaction/action. It looks like I misunderstand the purpose of OTP because I thought that it'd be more safely to use it instead of generating tokens by my own.

Comment: TOTP allows you to share a secret with a user that means that they can generate a code that you can then verify. It doesn't sound like this is what you are doing in this case. So your previous version likely works better for your use case.

Comment: @philnash, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but my question is still valid. Should I allow user to have multiple these tokens/codes at the same time? Is it a good/bad decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no problem in allowing users to have multiple tokens that are valid at the same time for different actions. As long as each token is restricted to authorising the action they are intended for and the tokens time out accordingly if they are not used.